# Why does a certain file always gets opened on startup?

Tags: files, desktop

I'm using `desktop-save-mode` to automatically open the files that I had opened in the last session. This mode should also remember the files that I closed so that it no longer opens them in the next session. However, there is one file, say `a.tex`, that gets opened every time I start emacs regardless of having closed it in the last session. Interestingly, if I run emacs with the `--no-desktop` flag, the file `a.tex` doesn't get opened automatically. Why is `desktop-mode` opening the file? How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Have a look at your desktop file.  Was it last saved when you expected it to have been saved?  Is the problem file listed?

Comment: Alright, looking at the desktop file I found that I had another TeX file whose TeX-master file was `a.tex`. Closing that file solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the desktop file I found I had another TeX file in my saved session whose TeX-master file was `a.tex`. Closing that file solved the issue.

Perhaps `auctex` or some other TeX-mode was opening `a.tex` whenever the other file was opened at startup when restoring the saved session?